# Find the entire arc length of the curve $r=2acos^3(θ/3)$

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

**Question: Find the entire arc length of the curve** $r=2a \cos^3(\frac{\theta}{3})$

My attempt:   Given, $r = 2a \cos^3(\frac{\theta}{3})$

Using chain rule while differentiating with respect to $\theta$,

$ \displaystyle \frac{dr}{dθ} = \frac{d}{d\theta} (2a \cos^3 \frac{\theta}{3})$

```
        = 2a * d / dθ [cos^3(θ/3)

        = 2a * 3 cos^2(θ/3) * d/dθ [cos(θ/3)]

        = 6a cos^3(θ/3) * [-sin(θ/3)] * d/dθ [θ/3]

        = 6a cos^3(θ/3) * [-sin(θ/3)] * 1/3

        = -2a*cos^2(θ/3)*sin(θ/3)
```

Now, As Tom K mentioned in his comment,

$ \cos(3π + \theta) = - \cos \theta$

$(\cos (3 π + \theta), \sin(3 π + \theta)) = - (\cos \theta, \sin\theta)$

This means values of x and y repeat every $3 \pi$.

Now, for the arc length $L$, integrate $ \displaystyle \sqrt {r^2 + \bigg(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\bigg)^2} \ d\theta \ $ with $ \ \theta \in (0,3\pi)$.

(**I have slove this far.Now,what should i d0.Seeking help from seniors**)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $r^2+(r')^2$ simplify very nicely

Comment: you must start using mathjax to write your math on the site. Someone edited your question yesterday. Did you try to edit and see how they wrote? I have edited part of your question, wherever I could. Please go through it and going forward, pls use mathjax.